# Download image from web url in java?

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/Work/images/abt.jpg");

InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int n=0;
while (-1!=(n=in.read(buf)))
{
   out.write(buf, 0, n);
}
out.close();
in.close();
byte[] response1 = out.toByteArray();

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C://abt.jpg");
fos.write(response1);
fos.close();
```

in this code there is some error in last 3 lines

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet ImageDownloadServlet threw exception java.io.**FileNotFoundException**: C:/abt.jpg (No such file or directory)

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String filePath = request.getParameter("action");
        System.out.println(filePath);
        // URL url = new
        // URL("http://localhost:8080/Works/images/abt.jpg");
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=icon" + ".jpg");
        URL url = new URL(filePath);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

        BufferedOutputStream outs = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
        int len;
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        while ((len = stream.read(buf)) > 0) {
            outs.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        outs.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

maybe try switching `C:/abt.jpg` to `C:\\abt.jpg`

Comment: On Windows systems, at least those based on NT (i.e. Windows NT, XP, Vista, and 7), the forward slash ("/") is a valid file path component separator and may be used in place of the official back slash ("\"). However, the forward slash does not need to be escaped.

Comment: tested and you are right. Strange the fact that it works both ways. ("//" and "/")

Answer (score 3):

Try using File.pathSeparator instead of slash.

Answer (score 2):

`("C://abt.jpg");`

try reversing the slashes

`("C:\\abt.jpg");`

I looked up a [example link](http://www.ecrion.com/products/xfrenderingserver/XFUltrascaleHelp/java_sample_application.htm) to a FOS  to C drive example, and the demo had them the other way.

Comment: On Windows systems, at least those based on NT (i.e. Windows NT, XP, Vista, and 7), the forward slash ("/") is a valid file path component separator and may be used in place of the official back slash ("\"). However, the forward slash does not need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
                IOException, MalformedURLException {
        String filePath = request.getParameter("action");
        // String filename = "abt.jpg";
        System.out.println(filePath);
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/Works/images/abt.jpg");

        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int n = 0;
        while (-1 != (n = in.read(buf))) {
            out.write(buf, 0, n);
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
        byte[] response1 = out.toByteArray();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/home/user/Downloads/abt.jpg");
        fos.write(response1);
        fos.close();

    }
```

this image will be in download folder